# Wrong display diagonal size

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

Absolutely new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, but the side menu and top menu do not appear on the screen. I have tried finding a way to fixcitcwith xrandr, but no luck so far. The displays menu shows it as a 32" screen when it is a 57" screen. Any idea for a fix

14.04 Ubuntu
Mitsubishi 57 inch screen WD-57831
Connected by DVI

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a place to look.  When I originally setup my PC to my big screen monitor I had to do an automatic image adjust from within the monitors menu system what your experiencing sounds quite similar like you I was only able to see a portion of the projected display you may also want to fiddle with hdmi -> dvi converters these can sometimes be helpful when fine tuning the display with PCs attached to large displays..

Sean